# Cauchy distribution: R code

Tags: r, median, cauchy-distribution

Generate 1000 sets of numbers from the Cauchy distribution. Do this for set size 2, 5, 10 and 20. Compute the median of each set. Find the distribution of the medians, for each set size.
How do I create the set size of 2,5,10, and 20?

Comment: Random number generators in R always start with `r`. Try `?rcauchy`.

Comment: I am using dcauchy

Comment: If you are after an empirical distribution for the median then it might be faster to compute the median of a uniform distributed variable and then transform this median to the median of a Cauchy distribution (see [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) how this works). In this way, in order to compute te median of one single set of Cauchy distributed variables, you only need one or two calls to compute a Cauchy distribution (using `qcauchy`) instead of up to 20 times `rcauchy`.

Comment: You could also compute this order statistic for the uniform distribution based on the beta distribution and you have no need for performing simulations with random generated numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to simulate 1000 random variables time the set size.

The following code will give you a matrix of 1000 row and a number of column corresponding to the set size.

```
set_number <- 1000
set_size <- 2
location <- 0
scale <- 1
mat <- matrix(data = rcauchy(set_number*set_size, location, scale), nrow = set_number, ncol = set_size)
```

You can then perform your calculations on each row.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question!
The question is basically asking to run 1000 iterations of Cauchy distribution generated numbers for sets of sizes of 2 variables, 5 variables, 10 variables, and 20 variables.

The solution below demonstrates how to solve the step with 2 variables.

**Step 1:** Create an empty matrix with zeros, 2 columns, and 1000 rows.

```
m1 <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 1000)
```

**Step 2:** Frame this matrix as `data.frame`.

```
m1 < -data.frame(m1)
```

**Step 3:** Create a loop that runs 1000 times. Each run the loop creates new 2 values from Cauchy distribution and replaces each subsequent row with these values.

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  x <- rcauchy(2)
  m1[i, ] <- x
}
```

Comment: In R you want to avoid loops when you can. See my answer below.

Comment: If you are working with a larger set of variables, like in this case (2,5,10,20), it's the best to define a loop that runs for the number of variables you need, otherwise you have to manually change the values in the code.

Comment: Yes i agree with a loop over the set size. I disagree with the loop you provided in your code to fill the matrix.

Comment: Sure, it's a legitimate point. I based my answer on the assumption that the person will integrate it in another loop so it runs 4 times for all sets they need.

Comment: Unless we are working with big data, the speed difference in performance between apply-family statements and for loops is negligible. I find that for loops are easier for people to understand—since R is unique in its apply-family functions—which makes them suitable for answering questions like this. In my opinion, it helps people understand the concept behind the code, which is what CrossValidated is about anyways.

Comment: I'd argue with it being helping in the long run as my job is literraly to remove for loops in sloppy R code. Is there any SE guideline on that matter (understandability vs. general efficiency) ?